# Excel VBA Pasting to Range with Variable Row

Tags: excel, vba, variables, row, paste

I am trying to paste into a range with a variable row. The row is based on the last row + 1. I am getting a debug error when I try to run the code. It should be B2:T2, B3:T3, etc. based on the last row plus one.

I used the standard copy paste with range/cells and the variable for the row. My other copy paste's in the application work just fine.

```
Dim lr As Integer, cr As Integer
      Dim r As Range
      
      lr = wb_main.Worksheets("Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
      cr = lr + 1
      Set r = wb_main.Worksheets("Data").Range("A" & lr)
      r.Offset(1).Value = r.Value + 1
      
      wb_main.Worksheets("Main").Range("E3:W3").Copy wb_main.Worksheets("Data").Range(Cells(cr, 2), Cells(cr, 20))
      wb_main.Worksheets("Main").Range("E3:W3").Delete
```

Comment: What error number and text are you getting, and on which line?

Comment: 'wb_main.Worksheets("Data").Range(Cells(cr, 2), Cells(cr, 20))' here. The copy before it works and the delete after works as well when I remove the paste.

Comment: Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: When I message box cr it shows the correct row number. I think it has to do with the range/cells combo. I tried it like this and with the "B"/"T" syntax with nothing that worked.

Comment: "`wb_main.Worksheets("Data").Range(Cells(cr, 2), Cells(cr, 20))`" doesn't show up in the sample code provided above, are you sure you included all relevant parts of your code?

Comment: ''''wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A44").Copy
      wb_main.Worksheets("Main").Range("W3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues'''' is used a little bit above and works fine. When I make the range/cells combo just .Range("B3:T3") it works just fine. Then I add in the Cells instead of "B3:T3" and it gets the error.

Comment: try `wb_main.Worksheets("Main").Range("E3:W3").Copy wb_main.Worksheets("Data").Range(wb_main.Worksheets("Data").Cells(cr, 2), wb_main.Worksheets("Data").Cells(cr, 20))`

Comment: @JohnM, that worked. Thank you. Is there an alternative to doing that, or can I create a variable that would hold "wb_main.Worksheet("Data")" so I don't have to keep typing it? I tried .Cells and just got a syntax error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to qualify both .Cells in the same way as you did .Range

One option is:

```
Dim wks As Worksheet
Set wks = wb_main.Worksheets("Data")
wb_main.Worksheets("Main").Range("E3:W3").Copy wks.Range(wks.Cells(cr, 2), wks.Cells(cr, 20))
```